# Find method to get records in DB returning empty datasets

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql, go-gorm

Now, I try to make an API with using GAE+CloudSQL.
I made this code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

var db *gorm.DB

func main() {
    db = DB()

    http.HandleFunc("/user", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer db.Close()
        var people []Person
        db.Find(&people)
        str, _ := json.Marshal(people)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", str)
        return
    })

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
}

func DB() *gorm.DB {
    var (
        connectionName = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME")
        user           = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_USER")
        password       = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD")
        socket         = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_SOCKET_PREFIX")
        databaseName   = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_DATABASE_NAME")
        option         = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_OPTION")
    )

    if socket == "" {
        socket = "/cloudsql"
    }
    if option == "" {
        option = "?parseTime=true"
    }

    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@unix(%s/%s)/%s%s", user, password, socket, connectionName, databaseName, option)
    conn, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("DB: %v", err))
    }

    return conn
}
```

With the help of cloud I can get people data.

> people.length is equal to the number of DB datas.

But, what I am getting is

> person.Name is "" and person.Age = 0.

I cannot understand why I could not get any data.
Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: can you share the list of field names of particular table? or better if you can share the table scheme

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
My using table is this.
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+
| id | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at | name    | age  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+

Comment: And, infomation_schema is this.

TABLE_CATALOG   : def
TABLE_SCHEMA    : bookshelf
TABLE_NAME      : people
TABLE_TYPE      : BASE TABLE
ENGINE          : InnoDB
VERSION         : 10
ROW_FORMAT      : Dynamic
TABLE_ROWS      : 9
AVG_ROW_LENGTH  : 1820
DATA_LENGTH     : 16384
DATA_FREE       : 0
AUTO_INCREMENT  : 11
CREATE_TIME     : 2019-06-24 14:02:25
UPDATE_TIME     : 2019-07-11 16:17:04
CHECK_TIME      :  NULL 
TABLE_COLLATION : utf8_general_ci
CHECKSUM        : NULL
CREATE_OPTIONS  : 
TABLE_COMMENT   :

Answer (score -1):

I found how to be able to get correct `person.Name` and `person.Age`.

I've wrote `defer db.Close()` in `http.HandleFunc`. So, once this function is called, DB connection is closed.

I should put `defer db.Close()` at the beginning of the main function.

I'm sorry for a simple mistake, but refreshed to understand.